# Identification techniques when $E(u_i|\text{do}(X_i))\not=0$

Tags: regression, causality, identifiability

In [this](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2338705) article Chen & Pearl make the following 2 statements:

- "*Identification techniques are available for models in which X is far from satisfying $E(u_i|X_i)=0$*" in response to Stock & Watson's sentence: "In observational data, X is not randomly assigned in an experiment. Instead, the best that can be hoped for is that X is *as if* randomly assigned, in the precise sense that $E(u_i|X_i)$=0"
- "*There are many techniques that allow unbiased estimation of causal

  effects even when other factors are not held fixed*" in response to Wooldridge's sentence: "If other factors are not held fixed, then we cannot know the causal effect of a price change on quantity demanded."

Can someone list the techniques they are referring to?

Comment: Did you miss $\text{do}(\cdot)$ in the body?

Comment: Good question, Richard. In the text, this is a quote of Chen & Pearl who are using the Economists' speak of $E(u_i|X_i)$ to really refer to $E(u_i|do(X_i))$

Comment: Instrumental variables and difference-in-differences come to mind. Each requires a different assumption to identify the effect.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, I meant the discrepancy between the title and the body. Is it intentional? (I now see the quote in the body is accurate.)

Comment: @RichardHardy: Yes, it is intentional. The title is the way Chen & Pearl would have written it (and the way perhaps it is time Econometrics books write it), while body has exact quotes from textbooks.

Comment: @Noah: Do you care to expand your comment into an answer?